# Using New Process() in C#, how can I copy the command line text to a text file?

Tags: c#, processstartinfo

I want to run lmutil.exe with the arguments -a, -c, and 3400@takd, then put everything that command line prompt generates into a text file.  What I have below isn't working.

If I step through the process, I get errors like "threw an exception of type System.InvalidOperationException"

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\FlexLM\lmutil.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "lmstat -a -c 3400@tkad>Report.txt";
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
```

All I want is for the command line output to be written to Report.txt

Comment: What about a space between `3400@tkad` and `>Report.txt`?

Comment: also what is the > for in the 34000@tkad

Comment: Filename = "cmd.exe", Arguments = "/c c:\flex..yadayada > Report.txt"

Comment: a space doesn't help, and the > is to denote that it is supposed to copy the output into the text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `Process` output you can use the `StandardOutput` property documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx).

Then you can write it to a file:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\FlexLM\lmutil.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "lmstat -a -c 3400@tkad";
p.Start();
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("Report.txt", p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
p.WaitForExit();
p.Close();
```

Comment: Okay, but then remove `>Report.txt' from the arguments.

Comment: This is working. I had thought it would put it in the directory of lmutil.exe.  Instead its in the bin folder of the c# program I'm running. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `>` to redirect via Process, you have to use `StandardOutput`. Also note that for it to work `StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` has to be set to true.